# Crash on [__NSCFConstantString gck_matchesPattern:]

Tags: ios, google-cast

When you are creating a Chromecast iOS app by yourself, not copied from [cast-ios-sample](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-sample), it will crash because the framework raises an uncaught exception.

```
[__NSCFConstantString gck_matchesPattern:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c99c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "-ObjC" to "Other Linker Flags" in the Build Settings for your target app in Xcode, as the sample app does.

Answer (score 2):

Add **-all_load** in Target section --> **Other Linker Flag**